# Magento 2 : Load/Get Orders by Direct Queries

Tags: magento2, order-grid, query

I have multiple Order Id in foreach loop, and I want to load or get orders by these order_ids.

I have used this code

```
if ($requestName == 'sales_order_grid_data_source') {
    if ($result instanceof $this->collection) 
    {
        $select = $this->collection->getSelect();
        if(!empty($filtered_order_id))
        {
            foreach($filtered_order_id as $order_id)
            {
                //order id here........... like 6, 7, 8
                //what to do here?? 
                $select->('main_table.entity_id = '.$order_id.'');
            }    
        }
        return $this->collection;
    }
}
```

Please suggest any solution?

Comment: Why you do not use Magento collection in order to retrieve orders ?

Comment: i already used that

Comment: So you can use the AddFieldToFilter to perform a where IN ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to understand what you are performing but if you need to place where clause in your select query you can perform like this

```
 $select->where('main_table.entity_id = '.$order_id);
```

If there are multiple records you and do something like this

```
$order_id = implode(',', array(1,2,3));
$select->where('main_table.entity_id IN (?)', $order);
```

Comment: got this error

`Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Learning/HelloPage/Plugin/OrderDataProvider.php on line 113`

Comment: used this one
`$order_id= array(1,2,3);   
                $select->where('main_table.entity_id IN '.$order_id);`

Comment: I have updated my answer when you use "IN"  clause you need to pass string not array so You need to convert your array to string.

Comment: please keep in touch as im just a beginner in magento..so i will need your help in future

Comment: You can create as many question as you want thats the beauty of this site :)

Comment: woah there is a problem, my other pages are not working, got this
`Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function setPageSize() on null in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0`

Comment: which other pages?

Comment: solved it, sorry to interupt